# Inconsistencies in ASCII conversion of UTF-8 in Properties files

Tags: java

Does anyone know why native2ascii generates lower-case hex codes, while Properties.store() produces upper-case hex?

Example:

保存 is encoded as `\u4FDD\u5B58` when using `Properties.store()`, but is encoded as `\u4fdd\u5b58` when using `native2ascii`

Is there any way to control this?

Comment: Lowercase or uppercase hex doesn't really matter.

Comment: That's right. It doesn't matter to Java, but I'm curious about why they're different. I figured native2ascii and Properties.store() would use the same toHex() method, but they obviously don't, which is what I'd like to explore

Comment: It doesn't matter in any language. f=F=15=fifteen. The use of upper/lowercase is just a preference/readability. The underlying value is still 15.

Comment: I meant that it doesn't matter to the JVM, but it matters if you're doing a diff of two files that have escaped unicode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why but I do know it doesn't matter (to Java anyway, it may matter to you a great deal). Unicode escapes are allowed to have upper *or* lower case hex digits so it really doesn't matter to Java which one is used (even mixed case is valid).

The reason they're different is probably something as simple as they were written by two different people.

Is there any way to control it? Not easily from what I can see. It doesn't appear that `native2ascii` has any options to control that output (it allows options to control the JVM but not to that level).

`Properties.store()` uses an `OutputStream` (and `Properties.load()` uses an `InputStream`) which you could probably subclass to filter the Unicode escapes but that seems an awful lot of work for (what looks like) dubious benefit.

Perhaps if you could tell us *why* you need this, there may be another way.

*Update 1:*

One thing that you *could* do is to pass the `native2ascii` output through a filter which turns the Unicode escape sequeces into uppercase. The following code `ucunicode.c` should be able to do this although I've only given it cursory testing. Simply execute:

```
native2ascii inputFile | ucunicode
```

and you should see the likes of `\u00EF\u00BB\u00BF` instead of `\u00ef\u00bb\u00bf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int count = 0;     // used for converting four hex digits after "\u".
    int chminus2 = -1; // character from two passes ago.
    int chminus1 = -1; // character from one pass ago.
    int ch;            // character for this pass.

    // Standard filter loop.

    while ((ch = getc (stdin)) != EOF) {
        if (count-- > 0) {
            // If processing Unicode escape sequence, uppercase letters.

            putchar (((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'f')) ? ch - 'a' + 'A' : ch);
        } else {
            // Normal processing, detect escape sequence and flag it.

            if ((chminus2 != '\\') && (chminus1 == '\\') && (ch == 'u')) {
                count = 4;
            }

            // In any case, output the character.

            putchar (ch);
        }

        // Shift characters "left".

        chminus2 = chminus1;
        chminus1 = ch;
    }
    return 0;
```

}

There may be edge cases that this doesn't handle well. I'm pretty certain it will handle all valid input but may break on invalid input like `\u1\\u0000` but, since that means your `native2ascii` is broken, you'll need to debug them yourself. This is a good start however.

*Update 2:*

Or, as a last-ditch solution, the OpenJDK project has the actual [source files](http://www.java.net/download/openjdk/jdk7/promoted/b74/openjdk-7-ea-src-b74-15_oct_2009.zip) for `native2ascii` in `jdk\src\share\classes\sun\tools\native2ascii\` (and just about everything else that's not encumbered by copyright) which you could bring down and compile yourself (GPL2 applies). The files are `Main.java`, `A2NFilter.java` and `N2AFilter.java` (and a couple of resource files). You'd simply have to change `N2AFilter.java` to call:

```
String hex = Integer.toHexString(buf[i]).toUpperCase();
```

instead of just:

```
String hex = Integer.toHexString(buf[i]);
```

In fact, by examining that source code, you can see that `Properties.store()` (in `jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/Properties.java`) uses the following functions to create it's Unicode escapes:

```
private static final char[] hexDigit = {
    '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'
};
private static char toHex (int nibble) {
    return hexDigit[(nibble & 0xF)];
}
```

This explains why it generates upper case while `native2ascii` produces lower case.

Comment: Yeah, I know it doesn't matter. I was just curious about why they were different. It messes up diff's, which is how I first discovered it. If one developer, or a build tool is using native2ascii, and another developer is using NetBeans, then a diff between the two will show every string as different. Best practice, of course, is to always checkin the properties encoded in UTF-8, and make the native2ascii part of a checkout or build process. I can't control this at all times, however...

Comment: Uppercase hex digits weigh more, and could void the warranty on your digital scale's CPU.

Comment: Terrific answer. If I could up-vote you more, I would. Thanks!-

Answer (score 1):

I just hit on this, and I have a reason this is annoying: I just converted a (unicode) .properties-file to another (homebrewed XML) format, with an export function back to .properties. This function uses `Properties.store()`, while the original Unicode .properties was converted by ant via `native2ascii`. I now wanted to compare they produce a similar result, so applied `sort` on each and `diff` on the result. Most of the resulting different lines are in fact due to these case differences in the \u-escapes. (I think I'll use a quick sed script to convert the case of one of the files.)

---

So, here is our sed script: `s/\\u([0-9A-F]{4})/\\u\L\1\E/g` (changes to lowercase), or `s/\\u([0-9A-F]{4})/\\u\U\1\E/g` (changes to uppercase). I had to change a bit more, since `Properties.store()` also escaped more signs like `!` to `\!`, `=` to `\=`, `:` to `\:`.

Comment: (This is an answer, but I've the button {:-) see [FAQ-reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) - yes, you need neputation)

Comment: Yes, just found it. Thanks. (I'm really new here as a contributor.)